# Can't use methods with parameters to give me an output: Main.java:28: error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, class, oop, methods, constructor

So I'm trying to make a program that has 2 methods or constructors? I don't even know at this point but I want to give parameters in order to add 2 numbers and multiple a number by itself.

I am expected to get values of 3.14^2 and 14.67.

I get this error:

```
Main.java:28: error: cannot find symbol
    Main sum = new Add(1.0, 13.67);
                   ^
  symbol:   class Add
  location: class Main
1 error
```

My code:

```
public class Main {

    double squaredNum;
    double addedNum;

    public Main(double num) {
        squaredNum = num * num;
    }

    /*
      public void Add(double num1, double num2) {

      }
    */
    public void Add(double num1, double num2) {
        addedNum = num1 + num2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main pi = new Main(3.14);
        System.out.println(pi.squaredNum);

        Main sum = new Add(1.0, 13.67);
        System.out.println(sum.addedNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're confusing classes and methods.

Comment: Thought I was more or less confusing methods and constructors. I was trying to make 2 constructors for some reason.

Comment: Sure, but you're trying to make instances of classes (via a constructor) but `Add` is a method. `Main` is a constructor here but there's some fundamental confusion between the two.

Comment: Yeah well, I think my objective is to make 2 methods since constructors are helpers in that situation.

Comment: Add() is a method rather than a constructor. First, constructors have no return type. Second, constructors always have the name of the class, in this case "Main".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pi.Add` to invoke the `Add` method on the `pi` instance.

```java
pi.Add(1.0, 13.67);
System.out.println(pi.addedNum);
```

Comment: Interesting... So there I'm technically using Main as a constructor and Add as a method correct?

Comment: @KhosrawAzizi Yes.

Comment: So I could technically use `squaredNum = num * num;` in a method and disregard the constructor right? Or entirely remove the constructor?

Comment: @KhosrawAzizi Yes, you can.